# PuTTY key input at login

Tags: ssh, putty

I've seen many similar questions asked but I'm not sure that they will work with what I'm trying to do: I work with an EMR that has a MUMPS/cache backend. When I login via SSH using PuTTY, it asks me what environment I would like to further connect to etc. These aren't a command in the traditional sense and I was wondering if anyone knows if there's a way to give a simple input, such as after login: 1 (TST), 2 (Programmer Access) to get me directly to the environment that I'm trying to get to. Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not with PuTTY.

But for example [KiTTY](https://www.9bis.net/kitty/) (PuTTY clone) has an option that simulates keystrokes after login.

- Go to *Connection > Data > Login details > Command*.

[image]